# place footnote under table above caption

Tags: tables, footnotes, floatrow

I would like to place a `footnote` under a `table` and above the `caption`. Since I am using the `floatrow` package I went with `\floatfoot`, however there is no option to position `floatfoot` below the table and above the caption.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{caption}

\floatsetup[table]{footposition=bottom}
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont=bf}

\begin{document}

  \begin{table}

    \begin{tabular}{lr}
      Yellow & 3 \\
      Green & $k-3$ \\
    \end{tabular}

    \caption{Apples}
    \floatfoot{$k$ number of apples}

  \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `\RawCaption`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup[table]{labelfont=bf}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
      Yellow & 3 \\
      Green & $k-3$ \\
\end{tabular}
\RawCaption{\caption*{\footnotesize$k$ number of apples}}
\caption{Apples}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Or even a simple text line with the desired formatting:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup[table]{labelfont=bf}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
      Yellow & 3 \\
      Green & $k-3$ \\
\end{tabular}\par\medskip
{\footnotesize$k$ number of apples}
\caption{Apples}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how I control the vertical padding of the `rawcaption`, without affecting the padding of normal captions?

Answer (score 1):

The package [threeparttable](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable) provides tablenotes and should probably do what you want.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\floatsetup[table]{footposition=bottom}
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont=bf}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \begin{threeparttable}[b]
  \caption{Apples}
    \begin{tabular}{lr}
      Yellow & 3 \\
      Green & $k-3$ \\
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}{\footnotesize
      \item [] $k$ number of apples
                      }
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately the width of the tablenote is limited to the tablewidth. Hence I recommend defining a fixed tablewidth with `tabular*` like this:

```
\begin{tabular*}{0.5\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lr}
  ...
\end{tabular*}
```